# Assigning Interval on MATLAB Symbols

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

I have constant symbols such as

t = sym('t')

c = sym('c')

but I have to restrict these symbols with a constraint stating that t is between 0 and 1 (0 $\le$ t $\le$1). For c, 0 $\lt$ c $\lt$ 1 .

I can easily assign a number in matlab by just denoting

t = 0;

but I need help to put these symbols in an interval.

Normally, this question is also suitable for stackoverflow but I believe I can get a much proper answer here. Any help will be appreciated a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the `assume` command here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html